# how to count total comments and react of blogs

Tags: mysql, myisam, mysql-8.0

I have three tables blogs, blog_comments and blogs_reacts(which stores like, love and thanks reactions of users ON blogs)

I WANT to list all the blogs and their total number of comments and reacts,

I tried this sql statement but count numbers were wrong:

```
SELECT b.blog_id, title , description, 
        count(blog_comments_id) ,
        COUNT(blog_react_id) 
FROM blog_comments 
    RIGHT JOIN blogs b on blog_comments.blog_id = b.blog_id 
    LEFT JOIN blogs_reacts br on b.blog_id = br.blog_id 
GROUP BY b.blog_id
```

descriptions of tables are below:
blogs table

```
DESC blogs;
Field   Type    Null    Key Default Extra
blog_id bigint(20) unsigned NO  PRI     auto_increment
content_type    varchar(20) NO
title   varchar(128)    NO
description text    YES
image   varchar(255)    YES
user_id bigint(20) unsigned NO  MUL
created_at  timestamp   NO      CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
updated_at  timestamp   NO      CURRENT_TIMESTAMP   on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

blog_comments table:

```
DESC blog_comments;
Field   Type    Null    Key Default Extra
blog_comments_id    bigint(20) unsigned NO  PRI     auto_increment
comment_text    text    NO          
user_id bigint(20) unsigned NO          
blog_id bigint(20) unsigned NO          
created_at  timestamp   YES     CURRENT_TIMESTAMP   
updated_at  timestamp   NO      CURRENT_TIMESTAMP   on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

blogs_reacts table

```
DESC blogs_reacts;
Field   Type    Null    Key Default Extra
blog_react_id   bigint(20) unsigned NO  PRI     auto_increment
blog_id bigint(20) unsigned NO  MUL     
user_id bigint(20) unsigned NO          
react_type_id   int(11) NO          
created_at  timestamp   NO      CURRENT_TIMESTAMP   
updated_at  timestamp   NO      CURRENT_TIMESTAMP   on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

Please help me out

Comment: Does the query bring back the correct values for those rows that do have existing comments AND reacts, and missing values for blogs that do not have comments and/or reacts?

Comment: none of count is correct. AND both  `count(blog_comments_id) ,
        COUNT(blog_react_id) ` counts are showing same numbers